# django project: template having node_modules which i can not find in static folder

Tags: html, css, node.js, django, frontend

I downloaded an example template and want to use in django project. my all static files is in static folder, settings.py modified accordingly, but I'm facing problem in line

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css' %}">
```

after executing

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
```

this given path is not present in my static folder. I don't have idea about node.js. Can you tell me how my html page will look exactly what i downloaded. right now it is not loading any supporting file from static

Comment: Do you have node_modules available into your root project directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use  {% load staticfiles %} on top of page and update your import like

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css' %}">
```

make sure you run collectstatic command if DEBUG is FALSE

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```